# Facebook SDK Android . Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

[image]
[image]

I want to post in facebook . I have downloaded the facebook sdk and imported it as an existing code into workspace and then androidapp-->properties ....... Here is my Code

```
    package com.gamers_republic.game.android;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog;
import com.gamers_republic.game.IActivityRequestHandler;
import com.gamers_republic.game.SteveFallDown;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements
        IActivityRequestHandler {

    protected AdView adView;
    protected InterstitialAd fullAdView;
    UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    protected Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 1: {
                fullAdView.show();
                AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                fullAdView.loadAd(request);
                break;
            }
            case 0: {
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        View gameView = initializeForView(new SteveFallDown(this));

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId("adUnitId");
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        fullAdView = new InterstitialAd(this);
        fullAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3022412706061951/7319448225");

        AdRequest request1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        fullAdView.loadAd(request1);

        adView.loadAd(request);

        layout.addView(gameView);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        layout.addView(adView, adParams);

        setContentView(layout);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, null);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android").setApplicationName("Steve Falldown").setDescription("new App").build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data,
                new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall,
                            Exception error, Bundle data) {
                        Log.e("Activity",
                                String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(
                            FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
                        Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void showAds(boolean show) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? 1 : 0);
    }

}
```

Look game starts normally only it show an error when I press on post .

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't share the "error" with us ?

Comment: the error is in the second image

Answer (score 0):

This is your Key Hash ...

"   jnOp0cjdFeUygj/UcgMtJ5/qFXk=   "

Copy it and paste it where you created the facebook application.

Comment: try with this, sometimes the key hash isn't well created, expect it the key hash.(toast) @user3693550